# The definition of “Take wing”

Tags: meaning-in-context

I’ve got a problem with the definition of this idiom:”take wing”,
I saw a quote from Horace Greeley in which he used “wing” as a plural word:”Fame is a vapour, popularity an accident, and riches take wings. Only one thing endures and that is character.”
I wanted to know that, shall I use it as a way to express my relaxation?
For example:
“I was lying on the beach to take wing my thoughts.”

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

> I was lying on the beach to take wing my thoughts.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20wing) defines *take wing* as

> to begin to fly
> —often used figuratively
> Let your imagination take wing and explore the possibilities.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-wing) defines
*take wing* as

> a. to lift off or fly away

These definitions show that *take wing* is intransitive, and hence your example needs a modification:

> I was lying on the beach to **let my thoughts take wing**.

Comment: Thank you so much